# Searching txt / excel files in an ftp server with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, ftp

Searching Google and stackoverflow hasn't really given me the information I need, so I'm wondering if someone can help me regarding the general structure of an app I'd like to build.

Basically, is it possible to build a rails app that downloads files from an FTP server each day (the files are uploaded each morning to the FTP) so that users can go to the app and choose a file to search and search the file without having to download anything. It would pull up a full line of results (excel formatted text document) and display in the browser.

Is there a gem for this? I haven't started coding because I'm not sure this is possible. Does this depend on the hosting platform? For example, would this be possible on Heroku?

I'm fairly new to rails, and don't want to start if the above isn't possible, or an alternative (possibly better) way of searching the files exists. Can rails search the files if they're downloaded to a local machine that has excel installed?

Comment: Anyhting is possible!

Comment: There are many different ways to accomplish this, making this question too broad. In our environment, we rely on using `rsync` running from a crontab to move files from one machine to another. It's designed for this purpose and is very smart. That relieves your application from having to do something that it doesn't need to do, and speeds up your code's response. Setting up `rsync` is off-topic for Stack Overflow and needs to be asked on http://poweruser.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible but thats some work to do:

- Use [Net::FTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html) to download the files from the server
- Start a script that imports the files in an Indexing database like ThinkingSphinx, Solr,... You can find a video of how to deal with excel files [Here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel)
- Create an interface to search the indexed documents

You also need an engine to run the whole process once a day. Thats also not a problem, there are many schelduling engines for rails out there....

Comment: In otherwords, the roo gem can read txt or csv files that are downloaded to the server inside the rails app itself? The files do not have to be downloaded locally? Thanks for your help!

Comment: No they dont need to be downloaded to the client because the indexing database is server-side.